# Cloudify 3.1 workflow install fails with error "Failed to find "create_deployment_environment" execution for deployment nodcaller"

Tags: cloudify

We are trying to execute 1 workflow for the first time on the uploaded blueprints(simple.yaml - blueprints downloaded from git hub) and getting an error:

```
" Internal error occurred in manager REST server - RuntimeError: Failed to find "create_deployment_environment" execution for deployment deploy2 "
```

Logs are as below :

---

```
ubuntu@cloudifyprecise:/opt/celery/cloudify.management__worker/work$ clearat cloudify.management_worker.log# ps aux | grep celery

ubuntu   13217  0.1  1.9 194856 39664 ?        Ssl  Jul30  10:38 /opt/celery/cloudify.management__worker/env/bin/python -m celery.bin.celeryd --include=cloudify_system_workflows.deployment_environment,plugin_installer.tasks,worker_installer.tasks,riemann_controller.tasks,cloudify.plugins.workflows --broker=amqp:// -n celery.cloudify.management --events --app=cloudify --loglevel=debug -Q cloudify.management --logfile=/opt/celery/cloudify.management__worker/work/cloudify.management_worker.log --pidfile=/opt/celery/cloudify.management__worker/work/cloudify.management_worker.pid --autoscale=5,2 --maxtasksperchild=10

ubuntu   13245  0.0  1.6 119084 34520 ?        S    Jul30   0:22 /opt/celery/cloudify.management__worker/env/bin/python -m celery.bin.celeryd --include=cloudify_system_workflows.deployment_environment,plugin_installer.tasks,worker_installer.tasks,riemann_controller.tasks,cloudify.plugins.workflows --broker=amqp:// -n celery.cloudify.management --events --app=cloudify --loglevel=debug -Q cloudify.management --logfile=/opt/celery/cloudify.management__worker/work/cloudify.management_worker.log --pidfile=/opt/celery/cloudify.management__worker/work/cloudify.management_worker.pid --autoscale=5,2 --maxtasksperchild=10

ubuntu   13246  0.0  1.6 119084 34588 ?        S    Jul30   0:21 /opt/celery/cloudify.management__worker/env/bin/python -m celery.bin.celeryd --include=cloudify_system_workflows.deployment_environment,plugin_installer.tasks,worker_installer.tasks,riemann_controller.tasks,cloudify.plugins.workflows --broker=amqp:// -n celery.cloudify.management --events --app=cloudify --loglevel=debug -Q cloudify.management --logfile=/opt/celery/cloudify.management__worker/work/cloudify.management_worker.log --pidfile=/opt/celery/cloudify.management__worker/work/cloudify.management_worker.pid --autoscale=5,2 --maxtasksperchild=10

ubuntu   19572  0.0  0.0   8104   940 pts/8    S+   07:04   0:00 grep --color=auto celery



ubuntu@cloudifyprecise:/opt/celery/cloudify.management__worker/work$ cat cloudify.management_worker.log 

[2015-07-30 10:14:19,534: DEBUG/MainProcess] [Worker] Loading modules.

[2015-07-30 10:14:19,536: DEBUG/MainProcess] [Worker] Claiming components.

[2015-07-30 10:14:19,536: DEBUG/MainProcess] [Worker] Building boot step graph.

[2015-07-30 10:14:19,541: DEBUG/MainProcess] [Worker] New boot order: {ev, queues, beat, pool, mediator, autoreloader, timers, state-db, autoscaler, consumer}

[2015-07-30 10:14:19,551: DEBUG/MainProcess] Starting celery.worker.hub.Hub...

[2015-07-30 10:14:19,551: DEBUG/MainProcess] celery.worker.hub.Hub OK!

[2015-07-30 10:14:19,552: DEBUG/MainProcess] Starting celery.concurrency.processes.TaskPool...

[2015-07-30 10:14:19,555: DEBUG/MainProcess] celery.concurrency.processes.TaskPool OK!

[2015-07-30 10:14:19,556: DEBUG/MainProcess] Starting celery.worker.mediator.Mediator...

[2015-07-30 10:14:19,569: DEBUG/MainProcess] celery.worker.mediator.Mediator OK!

[2015-07-30 10:14:19,569: DEBUG/MainProcess] Starting __builtin__.NoneType...

[2015-07-30 10:14:19,570: DEBUG/MainProcess] __builtin__.NoneType OK!

[2015-07-30 10:14:19,570: DEBUG/MainProcess] Starting celery.worker.consumer.Consumer...

[2015-07-30 10:14:19,570: WARNING/MainProcess] celery@celery.cloudify.management ready.

[2015-07-30 10:14:19,570: DEBUG/MainProcess] consumer: Re-establishing connection to the broker...

[2015-07-30 10:14:19,587: DEBUG/MainProcess] Start from server, version: 0.9, properties: {u'information': u'Licensed under the MPL.  See http://www.rabbitmq.com/', u'product': u'RabbitMQ', u'copyright': u'Copyright (C) 2007-2013 GoPivotal, Inc.', u'capabilities': {u'exchange_exchange_bindings': True, u'connection.blocked': True, u'authentication_failure_close': True, u'basic.nack': True, u'consumer_priorities': True, u'consumer_cancel_notify': True, u'publisher_confirms': True}, u'platform': u'Erlang/OTP', u'version': u'3.2.4'}, mechanisms: [u'PLAIN', u'AMQPLAIN'], locales: [u'en_US']

[2015-07-30 10:14:19,590: DEBUG/MainProcess] Open OK!

[2015-07-30 10:14:19,590: INFO/MainProcess] consumer: Connected to amqp://guest@127.0.0.1:5672//.

[2015-07-30 10:14:19,591: DEBUG/MainProcess] using channel_id: 1

[2015-07-30 10:14:19,591: DEBUG/MainProcess] Channel open

[2015-07-30 10:14:19,599: DEBUG/MainProcess] consumer: basic.qos: prefetch_count->4

[2015-07-30 10:14:19,599: DEBUG/MainProcess] using channel_id: 2

[2015-07-30 10:14:19,600: DEBUG/MainProcess] Channel open

[2015-07-30 10:14:19,610: DEBUG/MainProcess] consumer: Ready to accept tasks!

ubuntu@cloudifyprecise:/opt/celery/cloudify.management__worker/work$
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the error code that you can find here: https://github.com/cloudify-cosmo/cloudify-manager/blob/3.1-build/rest-service/manager_rest/blueprints_manager.py
There could be several scenarios that you would get this error.
If for example you have deleted the deployment before running this workflow,or if you have stopped some of the services of the manager.

I would try to recreate this deployment and execute the install workflow to see if it does reproduce.